# How to get distinct values in an array and group by them in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, distinct-values

I have data as below, and I want to get the distinct values from array and count their occurance.

Data :

```
[
  {
    "key": "Dummy",
    "country_array": [
      "USA",
      "UK",
      "Italy"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Dummy",
    "country_array": [
      "USA",
      "Italy"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Dummy2",
    "country_array": [
      "USA"
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to have below output :

```
[
  {
    "country": "USA",
    "total": 2
  },
  {
    "country": "Italy",
    "total": 2
  },
  {
    "country": "UK",
    "total": 1
  }
]
```

I tried using below aggregate query, but I am not able to get the distinct values and correct result. Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks...

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "key": "Dummy"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "country_array": "$country_array"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Something like [this?](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v1s5_6VmlVO)

Comment: This can be resolve your query for final output [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jTJ1ACCS3dg)

Comment: Thanks a lot...! `unwind` was missing for me, this certainly helps.. Thanks a lot..!!

Comment: Just a one more question from the Performance perspective, as I know unwinding is costly operation in mongo, do we have any alternative to this or its the only way to get to this output.. Thanks again...!!

Comment: Can you please help me with,  I want to apply a regex on `country_array` and return only the matching results query. 
I tried using $filter, but somehow the condition is not getting satisfied, also used $addFields to mark the matching result as "true/false", but its returning all the results... Thanks..